# Changing radius according to music amplitude - Processing

Tags: dictionary, processing

I'm trying to map the radius of a circle and trying to increase/decrease the radius accordingly to the amp of the music.
This is the line of code, in processing, that I'm using to map the values. The radius value changes when I start the program, but then it doesn't have any interaction with the music.

```
 import processing.sound.*;
SoundFile file;
Amplitude amp;
AudioIn audioIn;

float posX = 150;
float posY = 200;
int cols = 3;
int rows = 3;
int raio;
Gradient[][]grad = new Gradient[cols][rows];

//timer
int startMillis;
int duration = 2000;

PImage bg;
PImage logo;


void setup() {
  size(600, 800);

  bg = loadImage("bg.jpg");
  logo = loadImage ("band.png");

  //sound
  file = new SoundFile (this, "song.mp3");
  file.play();

  amp = new Amplitude (this);
  audioIn = new AudioIn(this, 0);
  audioIn.start();
  amp.input(audioIn);

  //gradient
  startMillis = millis();
  ellipseMode(RADIUS);
  smooth();
  color c1 = color (253, 196, 80, 40);
  color c2 = color(254, 127, 168, 40);
  raio = (int) map(amp.analyze(), 0, 1, 10, 25);
  println(raio);

  for (int i=0; i<cols; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<rows; j++) {
      grad[i][j] = new Gradient (140+i*160, 200+j*180, raio, c1, c2, random(1, 2), random(1, 2));
    }
  }

  noStroke();
}

void draw () {

  background (bg);

  //image
  image(logo, 45, height/4);
  logo.resize(0, 450);

  smooth();
  raio = (int) map(amp.analyze(), 0,1, 10, 25);
  println(raio);

  //draw gradient
  for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {

      grad[i][j].desenhar_grad();
      if (millis() > startMillis + duration) {
        grad[i][j].move();
        tint(234, 140, 140, 15);
        image(logo, 45, height/4);
        logo.resize(0, 450);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The line is in setup and in draw function.

Am I mapping wrong?

Comment: *Where* do you have this line? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: The [documentation](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/sound/Amplitude_analyze_.html) for `analyze` says that this method returns a value between 0 and 1 -- so why are you using a value between -0.9 and 0.9? Also, while your edit helps, it still isn't a [mcve]. For example -- how are you declaring `amp` and hooking it to an audo input?

Comment: the radius (raio) values only change between 2 (17 and 18), and I don't understand why

Comment: The problem doesn't lie with `map` -- it almost certainly lies with code that you have neglected to show. Why not post a *complete* [mcve], one which allows others to replicate the problem?

Comment: I understood that you wanted something minimal and not complete. I'll update the code now